# Where can I find free text to learn Lie group analysis for solving nonlinear systems of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups

Can anyone please recommend to me free online text for learning Lie group analysis for solving nonlinear systems of differential equations? it is preferable that text is not too complicated, it would be great if it gives solved examples.

Comment: Actually, there are plenty of them. [Hydon's notes](https://www.kent.ac.uk/smsas/personal/ph282/papers/IJQC05corrected.pdf) were the most accessible and illustrative text that I've found a while ago. [Starrett's text](http://euler.nmt.edu/~jstarret/05-649LieGroupODEFinalVersion.pdf) is also quite interesting and accessible.